# Oracle database schema using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy, schema

I have a problem with SqlAlchemy. When I define the schema in my Oracle database, foreign keys are not recognized in other tables. Tested without using layout and it worked. But I need to define the schema of this application because the user is not the owner of the tables.
I would like your help to solve this problem.
code:

```
Base = declarative_base()
SCHEMA = {'schema' : 'SIATDESV'}

class Pgdasd(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'PGDASD'
    __table_args__ = SCHEMA

    PGDASD_00000_ID_DECLARACAO    = Column(String(17), primary_key = True)

class Pgdasd_01000(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'pgdasd_01000'
    __table_args__ = SCHEMA

    PGDASD_00000_ID_DECLARACAO  = Column(String, ForeignKey('PGDASD.PGDASD_00000_ID_DECLARACAO'))   
    PGDASD_01000_NRPAGTO        = Column(String, primary_key = True)
```

error:
***Foreign key associated with column 'pgdasd_01000.PGDASD_00000_ID_DECLARACAO' could not find table 'PGDASD' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'PGDASD_00000_ID_DECLARACAO'***

thanks!

Comment: Could you please add the following information from the logs - create table queries generated by SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: check that table(s) are created in db. BTW How did you create these tables? Have you run `metadata.create_all()` method ?

Step 2:
Try to add the name of the schema to the ForeignKey defintion:

```
Base = declarative_base()
SCHEMA = {'schema' : 'SIATDESV'}

class Pgdasd(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'PGDASD'
    __table_args__ = SCHEMA

    PGDASD_00000_ID_DECLARACAO    = Column(String(17), primary_key = True)

class Pgdasd_01000(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'pgdasd_01000'
    __table_args__ = SCHEMA

    PGDASD_00000_ID_DECLARACAO  = Column(String, ForeignKey('SIATDESV.PGDASD.PGDASD_00000_ID_DECLARACAO'))   
    PGDASD_01000_NRPAGTO        = Column(String, primary_key = True)
```

If this will help you may also make code to use schema value to avoid hardcoding the schema.

```
    PGDASD_00000_ID_DECLARACAO  = Column(String, ForeignKey(SCHEMA['schema']+'.PGDASD.PGDASD_00000_ID_DECLARACAO'))
```

PS: Anyway it is always useful to check SQLAlchemy log what SQL queries it generates.

Comment: The problem continues ...
When I inserted the foreign key in the scheme generated the same error.

Comment: Please make sure that there is table `PGDASD` in schema `SIATDESV` and it has such column.

Comment: Run the following query in sqlplus: `select PGDASD_00000_ID_DECLARACAO from  SIATDESV.PGDASD;` to check does such table exist in db. DB would complain if there are no such table or column.

Comment: I tested it now and it worked! I think I had done something wrong. Thank you!